# is there an option on Ruby like mysql_insert_id() for PHP?

Tags: mysql, ruby

Does ruby support a way to retrieve the id for the last inserted row simliar to php's `mysql_insert_id()` method for mysql databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can always use `SELECT last_insert_id()` query instead.

Answer (score 9):

It's pretty much the same in ruby, except that the mysql connection is wrapped by an object and that the library is available trough rubygems ( `gem install mysql` )

```
require 'mysql'
db = Mysql.connect(hostname, username, password, databasename)
db.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES 1,2,3");
db.insert_id
# => last inserted id
```

see http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/

Usually you don't do that and rely on a sql abstraction library like ActieRecord, DataMapper, Sequel, DBI, ... all of them have this method available but under different modules.

Comment: I think the methods have changed a bit. It's now `db.last_id`

Answer (score -1):

Why would you need that? Chances are that you're not using ActiveRecord to its full power. However, you can access the id of a created record by just accessing `@record.id`.

I would recommend to not use plain SQL syntax in Rails...

**Update:** Sorry, just realized you may in fact NOT be using ActiveRecord. Of course it's feasible to use the suggested `SELECT` syntax then (and it's the right way to obtain this value). Personally, I'd still prefer to use ActiveRecord.